# Set value in Angular reactive form with async dropdowns

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-reactive-forms

I'm writing a simple Angular application and faced an issue I can't resolve by reading the documentation.

I have a component which displays a form:

[image: The form]

The form consists of a few fields and, in common, some fields are simple inputs, some fields are dropdowns with values taken from services with async.

Markup of the form:

```
<h1 mat-dialog-title>Add device data</h1>
<form [formGroup]="formGroup" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(formGroup)">
    <div mat-dialog-content>
        <p>
            <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
                <mat-label>Date</mat-label>
                <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" formControlName="date">
                <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>

                <mat-error *ngIf="formGroup.get('date')?.hasError('required')">
                    Date is required
                </mat-error>
            </mat-form-field>
        </p>

        <p>
            <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
                <mat-label>Flat</mat-label>
                <mat-select formControlName="flat">
                    <mat-option *ngFor="let flat of flatService.flats$ | async" 
                                [value]="flat">
                        {{flat.title}}
                    </mat-option>
                </mat-select>

                <mat-error *ngIf="formGroup.get('flat')?.hasError('required')">
                    Flat is required
                </mat-error>
            </mat-form-field>
        </p>

        <p>
            <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
                <mat-label>Device</mat-label>
                <mat-select formControlName="device">
                    <mat-option *ngFor="let device of devices$ | async" 
                                [value]="device">
                        {{device.title}}
                    </mat-option>
                </mat-select>

                <mat-error *ngIf="formGroup.get('device')?.hasError('required')">
                    Device is required
                </mat-error>
            </mat-form-field>
        </p>

        <p *ngIf="(features$ | async)?.includes('readings')">
            <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
                <mat-label>Device reading</mat-label>
                <input type="number" matInput formControlName="reading">
            
                <mat-error *ngIf="formGroup.get('reading')?.hasError('pattern')">
                    Device reading should contain numbers only
                </mat-error>
            </mat-form-field>
        </p>

        <p *ngIf="(features$ | async)?.includes('invoices')">
            <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
                <mat-label>Invoice</mat-label>
                <app-file-upload formControlName="invoiceFile"></app-file-upload>
            </mat-form-field>
        </p>

        <p *ngIf="(features$ | async)?.includes('receipts')">
            <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
                <mat-label>Receipt</mat-label>
                <app-file-upload formControlName="receiptFile"></app-file-upload>
            </mat-form-field>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div mat-dialog-actions>
        <button mat-button (click)="onCancel()" type="reset">Cancel</button>
        <button mat-button [disabled]="!formGroup.valid" type="submit">Save</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Underlying component TS code:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-dashboard-device-dialog',
    templateUrl: './device-dialog.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./device-dialog.component.css']
})
export class DashboardDeviceDialogComponent implements OnInit {
    devices$: Observable<Device[]>;
    features$: Observable<string[]> = new Observable<string[]>();

    formGroup = new FormGroup({
        date: new FormControl(new Date(), [Validators.required]),
        flat: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]),
        device: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]),
        reading: new FormControl('', [Validators.pattern('\\d+')]),
        invoiceFile: new FormControl(null),
        receiptFile: new FormControl(null)
    });

    constructor(
        public flatService: FlatService,
        private deviceService: DeviceService,
        private dataService: DataService, 
        private dialog: MatDialogRef<DashboardDeviceDialogComponent>,
        @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public dialogData: DeviceDialogData
    ) {     
        const flatChange$ = this.formGroup.get('flat')?.valueChanges as Observable<Flat>;
        this.devices$ = this.deviceService.findAllByFlat(flatChange$);

        const deviceChange$ = this.formGroup.get('device')?.valueChanges as Observable<Device>;
        this.features$ = deviceChange$.pipe(
            filter(device => device != null),
            map(device => this.extractFeatures(device))
        );
    }

    private extractFeatures(device: Device): string[] {
        const result: string[] = [];
        if (device.needReceipts) {
            result.push('receipts');
        }
        if (device.needInvoices) {
            result.push('invoices');
        }
        if (device.needReadings) {
            result.push('readings');
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

In common, the form is pretty simple and it works gracefully when a new record is created - all the dropdowns are populated, all the dependencies between fields are working correctly.

But edit of the existing record is not working - dropdowns have no value selected. The code I used for setting the value is simple (I even tried to use `form.patchValue()` - the same):

```
if (this.dialogData?.record) {
  const record = this.dialogData.record;
  this.formGroup.setValue(record);
}
```

Record in the `this.dialogData?.record` is the instance of ```DataRecord`` (set of fields is the same):

```
export interface DataRecord {
    date: Date
    flat: Flat
    device: Device
    reading: number
    invoiceFile?: FileId | null
    receiptFile?: FileId | null
}
```

How to properly set value to the form like this?

Comment: I believe the value you patch should also be in the list of the options. the form controls most likely actually contains the  value you want, but it is not displayed because there is no corresponding option

Answer (score 0):

As soon as I posted my question I decided to have a walk and within first five minutes I managed to come up with an idea which next was proofed by code.

The problem is in the object's equality - I'm using objects as values in the form:

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let flat of flatService.flats$ | async" 
    [value]="flat">
    {{flat.title}}
</mat-option>
```

And in my model I have properties of the object type:

```
export interface DataRecord {
    date: Date
    flat: Flat
    ...
}
```

Because I can't define a method which compares two objects (like in Java), objects are compared by reference (using `==` or `===`). So that my `Flat` object in the dropdown and the `Flat` object in the record are different.

The solution was to get use identifiers instead of references:

```
export interface DataRecord {
    date: Date
    flat: string
    device: string
    ...
}
```